# Wrong image size when exporting to pdf

Tags: export, pdf-format

I'm having trouble in getting a plot adequate size when exporting as pdf. When I select my cell and use "Save Selection As...", everything turns almost ok. Sadly, I get an annoying "Out[]" mark near the image.

[image: Saved by selecting cell and using "Save Selection As..."]

However, if I use

```
Export["myPlot.pdf", myPlot]
```

the image is totally out of proportion.

[image: Saved using Export[]]

Some answers to similar questions mentioned that printing as pdf uses a different environment (which re-scaled the plots) and suggested adding

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, PrintingStyleEnvironment -> "Working"]
```

but this did not solve this problem as both images were taken after re-setting the printing style environment.

I wouldn't mind using the "Save Selection As..." option if the cell mark did not appear (again, I've only noticed this for the pdf format, png works perfectly) but I'm also somewhat bothered by why isn't my export working the way I want it to. I've tried different suggestions from the web (e.g. changing image size or resolution) but to no avail. If it helps, the original plot ImageSize is set to Full.

PS: The originals were in pdf format, but were converted to png so that I could upload them into this question.

Edit:
Code to generate the plot:

```
(*Plot of conical data points*)
plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameterConical = 
ListLogLogPlot[Table[Labeled[{conicalData[[i,3]]*conicalData[[i,4]]^2, conicalData[[i,6]]}, conicalData[[i,1]], 
 Above], {i, 2, Length[conicalData]}], 
ImageSize -> Full, 
PlotRange -> {{1, 1000}, {1, 1000}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Row[{"Volume parameter/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}], Row[{"Pressurised volume/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}]}, 
TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> ticksFontSize],
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize},
PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsolutePointSize[pointSize]], 
GridLines -> Automatic,
Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]

(*Plot of spherical or cylindrical data points*)
plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameterSphericalOrCylindrical = ListLogLogPlot[Table[Labeled[{sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,3]]*sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,4]]^2, sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,6]]}, 
 If[sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,1]] == "Voskhod", (##1 & )[], If[sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,1]] == "Vostok", "Vostok and Voskhod", 
   sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,1]]]], If[sphericalOrCylindricalData[[i,1]] == "Shenzhou", After, Above]], {i, 2, Length[sphericalOrCylindricalData]}], 
ImageSize -> Full,
PlotStyle -> {ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], Directive[AbsolutePointSize[pointSize]]}, 
PlotRange -> {{1, 1000}, {1, 1000}}, 
FrameLabel -> {Row[{"Volume parameter/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}], Row[{"Pressurised volume/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}]}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize}, 
TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> ticksFontSize], 
GridLines -> Automatic, 
Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]

(*Joining the two plots above and adding a legend*)
plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameter = Legended[Show[{plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameterConical, 
 plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameterSphericalOrCylindrical}], 
Placed[PointLegend[{Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[1]], AbsolutePointSize[pointSize]], Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[2]], 
   AbsolutePointSize[pointSize]]}, {"Conical", "Spherical or cylindrical"}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize},
LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below]]

(*Plotting the a fit for each of the data types above*)
plotFitPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameter = LogLogPlot[{fitConicalData, fitSphericalOrCylindricalData}, {x, 1, 1000}, 
PlotStyle -> {Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[3]], AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness]], Directive[ColorData[97, "ColorList"][[4]], 
  AbsoluteThickness[lineThickness]]},
PlotLegends -> Placed[{"Conical fit", "Spherical or cylindrical fit"}, Below],
ImageSize -> Full, 
FrameLabel -> {Row[{"Volume parameter/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}], Row[{"Pressurised volume/", Quantity[None, "Meters"^3]}]}, 
LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> labelFontSize},
TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> ticksFontSize],
GridLines -> Automatic,
Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}]

(*Joining everything in a single plot*)
myPlot = Show[plotPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameter, plotFitPressurisedVolumeVsVolumeParameter]
```

I was trying to avoid this since it's not that user friendly, but alas seems I cannot. If there is any other information that would be needed, don't hesitate to ask.

Edit II:

```
pointSize = 9; 
labelFontSize = 24; 
ticksFontSize = 16; 
lineThickness = 2;
```

Comment: Please provide the code where you assign `myPlot`.

Comment: Also you shouldn't do _"Save selection as..."_ but click on the plot and do _"Save graphic as..."_ if you want to avoid the `Out[...]` appearing in the plot.

Comment: @flinty that definitely works for the graph, but then I lose the legend on the bottom =(

Comment: You can select `Out[]` and delete it  before save as selection..

Comment: @Jak just wrap the plot in `Rasterize[...]` if you want the legend too.

Comment: @Jak You can also increase image size using `ImageSize[]`

Comment: @flinty wouldn't this waste the purpose of using a vector format like pdf or svg?

Comment: @OkkesDulgerci Selecting `Out[]` and deleting it made the trick. Regarding `ImageSize[]`, I've tried using it in `Export[]`, but it didn't influence the plot size in the pdf format. Honestly, I'm fine with using Okkes trick, but it would be nice if there was a way using `Export[]` too, since it would be easier to automate.

Comment: @Jak: some of your code seems to be missing: when I copy what you posted and paste it into a notebook and evaluate that, I get various errors and no actual plot. In fact, the posted code is missing definitions for `ticksFontSize`, `labelFontSize`, and pointSize` as well as the crucial definitions for `conicalData` and `sphericalOrCylindricalData`,

Comment: @murray `ticksFontSize` and `labelFontSize` are just values for the plots options (so that I could keep all my plots consistent). I've added them to the post. `conicalData` and `sphericalOrCylindricalData` are data imported from a csv file, so I don't have a way of replicating that here. I could post the code for the import as well, but it would still not work since the data file would be missing =(